# How to get a uniform distribution in a range [r1,r2] in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, uniform-distribution

I want to get a 2-D `torch.Tensor` with size `[a,b]` filled with values from a uniform distribution (in range `[r1,r2]`) in PyTorch.

Comment: idk if it's just me but I find that `torch.rand` is very bad naming. I'd have no idea if it's Gaussian or Uniform without looking at the docs (that btw take ages to load for some reason on a browser).

Comment: scratch my previous comment. Use this: `r2 = torch.torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub).sample((num_samples,Din))
`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If `U` is a random variable uniformly distributed on [0, 1], then `(r1 - r2) * U + r2` is uniformly distributed on [r1, r2].

Thus, you just need:

```
(r1 - r2) * torch.rand(a, b) + r2
```

Alternatively, you can simply use:

```
torch.FloatTensor(a, b).uniform_(r1, r2)
```

---

To fully explain this formulation, let's look at some concrete numbers:

```py
r1 = 2 # Create uniform random numbers in half-open interval [2.0, 5.0)
r2 = 5

a = 1  # Create tensor shape 1 x 7
b = 7
```

We can break down the expression `(r1 - r2) * torch.rand(a, b) + r2` as follows:

1. `torch.rand(a, b)` produces an `a x b` (1x7) tensor with numbers uniformly distributed in the range [0.0, 1.0).

```py
x = torch.rand(a, b)
print(x)
# tensor([[0.5671, 0.9814, 0.8324, 0.0241, 0.2072, 0.6192, 0.4704]])
```

2. `(r1 - r2) * torch.rand(a, b)` produces numbers distributed in the uniform range [0.0, -3.0)

```py
print((r1 - r2) * x)
tensor([[-1.7014, -2.9441, -2.4972, -0.0722, -0.6216, -1.8577, -1.4112]])
```

3. `(r1 - r2) * torch.rand(a, b) + r2` produces numbers in the uniform range [5.0, 2.0)

```py
print((r1 - r2) * x + r2)
tensor([[3.2986, 2.0559, 2.5028, 4.9278, 4.3784, 3.1423, 3.5888]])
```

---

Now, let's break down the answer suggested by @Jonasson: `(r2 - r1) * torch.rand(a, b) + r1`

1. Again, `torch.rand(a, b)` produces (1x7) numbers uniformly distributed in the range [0.0, 1.0).

```py
x = torch.rand(a, b)
print(x)
# tensor([[0.5671, 0.9814, 0.8324, 0.0241, 0.2072, 0.6192, 0.4704]])
```

2. `(r2 - r1) * torch.rand(a, b)` produces numbers uniformly distributed in the range [0.0, 3.0).

```py
print((r2 - r1) * x)
# tensor([[1.7014, 2.9441, 2.4972, 0.0722, 0.6216, 1.8577, 1.4112]])
```

3. `(r2 - r1) * torch.rand(a, b) + r1` produces numbers uniformly distributed in the range [2.0, 5.0)

```py
print((r2 - r1) * x + r1)
tensor([[3.7014, 4.9441, 4.4972, 2.0722, 2.6216, 3.8577, 3.4112]])
```

**In summary**, `(r1 - r2) * torch.rand(a, b) + r2` produces numbers in the range [r2, r1), while `(r2 - r1) * torch.rand(a, b) + r1` produces numbers in the range [r1, r2).

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way round? I.e. (r2-r1)*torch.rand(a,b) + r1?

Comment: Isn’t it the same?

Comment: @Jonasson: I think your answer is the better one.

Comment: @BiBi: No, they are not the same. I expanded your answer to give a more thorough explanation. Your answer produces numbers in the range `[r2, r1)`, while @Jonasson's answer produces numbers in the range `[r1, r2)`. Note that the intervals are half-open, meaning that your answer will never produce `r1` as a value, while @Jonasson's answer will.

Comment: I still don't understand why there isn't something like torch.uniform like there is is for Numpy.

Comment: idk if it's just me but I find that `torch.rand` is very bad naming. I'd have no idea if it's Gaussian or Uniform without looking at the docs (that btw take ages to load for some reason on a browser).

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 any single value in a continuous distribution has zero probability, so PDF's defined on a closed, open, or half open interval are [all equivalent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140805/in-the-definition-of-probability-density-function-does-it-matter-if-the-interva).

Comment: @CharlieParker [there is:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66600118/9067615) `torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform()`

Comment: @iacob : Look at the APIs, not the math.

Answer (score 35):

```
torch.FloatTensor(a, b).uniform_(r1, r2)
```

Comment: While the accepted answer goes into more detail on different methods, and how they work, this answer is the simplest.

Comment: I still don't understand why there isn't something like torch.uniform like there is is for Numpy.

Comment: @CharlieParker [there is:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66600118/9067615) `torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform() `

Answer (score 11):

Utilize the `torch.distributions` package to generate samples from different distributions.

For example to sample a 2d PyTorch tensor of size `[a,b]` from a uniform distribution of `range(low, high)` try the following sample code

```
import torch
a,b = 2,3   #dimension of the pytorch tensor to be generated
low,high = 0,1 #range of uniform distribution

x = torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform(low,high).sample([a,b])
```

Answer (score 4):

Please Can you try something like:

```
import torch as pt
pt.empty(2,3).uniform_(5,10).type(pt.FloatTensor)
```

Answer (score 4):

PyTorch has a number of distributions built in. You can build a tensor of the desired `shape` with elements drawn from a uniform distribution like so:

```py
from torch.distributions.uniform import Uniform

shape = 3,4
r1, r2 = 0,1

x = Uniform(r1, r2).sample(shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a uniform random distribution, you can use

```
torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform()
```

example,

```
import torch
from torch.distributions import uniform

distribution = uniform.Uniform(torch.Tensor([0.0]),torch.Tensor([5.0]))
distribution.sample(torch.Size([2,3])
```

This will give the output, tensor of size [2, 3].

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses NumPy to first produce a random matrix and then converts the matrix to a PyTorch tensor. I find the NumPy API to be easier to understand.

```py
import numpy as np

torch.from_numpy(np.random.uniform(low=r1, high=r2, size=(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

See this for all distributions: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform

This is the way I found works:

```
# generating uniform variables

import numpy as np

num_samples = 3
Din = 1
lb, ub = -1, 1

xn = np.random.uniform(low=lb, high=ub, size=(num_samples,Din))
print(xn)

import torch

sampler = torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub)
r = sampler.sample((num_samples,Din))

print(r)

r2 = torch.torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub).sample((num_samples,Din))

print(r2)

# process input
f = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('f1', nn.Linear(Din,Dout)),
    ('out', nn.SELU())
]))
Y = f(r2)
print(Y)
```

but I have to admit I don't know what the point of generating sampler is and why not just call it directly as I do in the one liner (last line of code).

Comments:

- sampler are good for it's so you can transform/compose/cache/etc distributions. see https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10604, and the top of the docs of https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html# and https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05254
- you can feed in tensors to uniform to let it know the high dimensional interval (hypercube) to generate the uniform samples (that's why it receives tensors as input rather than simply numbers)

---

Reference:

- [How to get a uniform distribution in a range [r1,r2] in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328530/how-to-get-a-uniform-distribution-in-a-range-r1-r2-in-pytorch/62919760#62919760)
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/generating-random-tensors-according-to-the-uniform-distribution-pytorch/53030/8
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/24162

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch (now?) has a random integer function that allows:

```
torch.randint(low=r1, high=r2, size=(1,), **kwargs)
```

and returns uniformly sampled random integers of shape *size* in range [r1, r2).

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randint.html