# How do I create a normal distribution in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, normal-distribution

I want to create a random normal distribution with a given mean and std.

Comment: see this for all distributions (so you can do something like `r2 = torch.torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub).sample((num_samples,Din))
`): https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform

Answer (score 26):

You can easily use [torch.Tensor.normal_()](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.normal_) method.

Let's create a matrix Z (a 1d tensor) of dimension `1 × 5`, filled with random elements samples from the normal distribution parameterized by `mean = 4` and `std = 0.5`.

```
torch.empty(5).normal_(mean=4,std=0.5)
```

Result:

```
tensor([4.1450, 4.0104, 4.0228, 4.4689, 3.7810])
```

Comment: Why if I compute the std and mean of the vector you posted, I obtained: `(tensor(4.0856), tensor(0.2514))`? Isn't the std supposed to be close to 0.5?

Comment: @muammar are you sure you are computing the standard deviation and not the variance?

Comment: @vaporK I think I am sure. Look at this: https://www.calculator.net/standard-deviation-calculator.html?numberinputs=4.1450%2C+4.0104%2C+4.0228%2C+4.4689%2C+3.7810&ctype=p&x=97&y=22

Comment: @muammar 0.2514 is not unusual since there are only 5 values. The standard error (0.5 / sqrt(5)) is 0.22, so 68% of the time you'll get a value between 0.276 and 0.723. If you change that 5 to a 5,000, the SE drops to 0.007 and you can expect a value much closer to 0.5.

Answer (score 14):

For a standard normal distribution (i.e. `mean=0` and `variance=1`), you can use `torch.randn()`

For your case of custom `mean` and `std`, you can use [**`torch.distributions.Normal()`**](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.normal.Normal)

---

> Init signature:
>   tdist.Normal(loc, scale, validate_args=None)
>
> Docstring:
>            Creates a normal (also called Gaussian) distribution parameterized by
>       `loc` and `scale`.
>
> Args:
>           loc (float or Tensor): mean of the distribution (often referred to as mu)
>           scale (float or Tensor): standard deviation of the distribution
>               (often referred to as sigma)

---

Here's an example:

```
In [32]: import torch.distributions as tdist

In [33]: n = tdist.Normal(torch.tensor([4.0]), torch.tensor([0.5]))

In [34]: n.sample((2,))
Out[34]: 
tensor([[ 3.6577],
        [ 4.7001]])
```

Answer (score 11):

A simple option is to use the `randn` function from the base module. It creates a random sample from the standard Gaussian distribution. To change the mean and the standard deviation you just use addition and multiplication. Below I create sample of size 5 from your requested distribution.

```
import torch
torch.randn(5) * 0.5 + 4 # tensor([4.1029, 4.5351, 2.8797, 3.1883, 4.3868])
```

Comment: Hello, I find following confusing: According to the PyTorch documentation: torch.rand returns a tensor filled with random numbers from a uniform distribution on the interval [0,1)
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.rand. I saw some developers use the same  code as you to create Gaussian distribution. I would appreciate if you can please elaborate further on this? Thank you

Comment: @Zvezda I am not sure what your question is. The `rand` function indeed samples from a uniform distribution but the `randn` function samples from a Gaussian https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.randn. Multiplying by the standard deviation and adding the mean is standard statistical practice.

Comment: Hello, @gui11aume, thank you a lot. I realized I didn't notice these two are two different functions - rand and randN.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your distribution like described [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.normal.Normal) in the docs.
In your case this should be the correct call, including sampling from the created distribution:

```py
from torch.distributions import normal

m = normal.Normal(4.0, 0.5)
s = m.sample()
```

If you want to get a sample of a certain size/shape, you can [pass it to `sample()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.normal.Normal.sample), for example

```py
s = m.sample([5, 5])
```

for a 5x5-Tensor.

Comment: what if you want to sample a specific size?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to generate.

For generating standard normal distribution use -

```
torch.randn()
```

for all all distribution (say normal, poisson or uniform etc) use
`torch.distributions.Normal()` or `torch.distribution.Uniform()`.
A detail of all these methods can be seen here - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#normal

Once you define these methods you can use .sample method to generate the number of instances. It also allows you to generates a sample_shape shaped sample or sample_shape shaped batch of samples if the distribution parameters are batched.

Answer (score 0):

For all distribution see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#

click on right menu to jump to normal (or search in the docs).

An example code:

```
import torch

num_samples = 3
Din = 1
mu, std = 0, 1
x = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(loc=mu, scale=std).sample((num_samples, Din))

print(x)
```

---

For details on torch distributions (with emphasis on uniform) see my SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62919760/1601580